# Create custom type in C# to handle rdap.org response format

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to create a custom type in C# that can handle rdap.org responses upon JSON deserialization (for my purposes I'll be using netwonsoft).

For example in making a GET request to: https://rdap.org/domain/stackoverflow.com
the following JSON string is returned:

```
{
    "objectClassName": "domain",
    "handle": "108907621_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN",
    "ldhName": "STACKOVERFLOW.COM",
    "links": [
        {
            "value": "https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/domain/STACKOVERFLOW.COM",
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://rdap.verisign.com/com/v1/domain/STACKOVERFLOW.COM",
            "type": "application/rdap+json"
        },
        {
            "value": "https://apis.cscglobal.com/dbs/rdap-api/v1/domain/STACKOVERFLOW.COM",
            "rel": "related",
            "href": "https://apis.cscglobal.com/dbs/rdap-api/v1/domain/STACKOVERFLOW.COM",
            "type": "application/rdap+json"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        "client transfer prohibited"
    ],
    "entities": [
        {
            "objectClassName": "entity",
            "handle": "299",
            "roles": [
                "registrar"
            ],
            "publicIds": [
                {
                    "type": "IANA Registrar ID",
                    "identifier": "299"
                }
            ],
            "vcardArray": [
                "vcard",
                [
                    [
                        "version",
                        {},
                        "text",
                        "4.0"
                    ],
                    [
                        "fn",
                        {},
                        "text",
                        "CSC Corporate Domains, Inc."
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "entities": [
                {
                    "objectClassName": "entity",
                    "roles": [
                        "abuse"
                    ],
                    "vcardArray": [
                        "vcard",
                        [
                            [
                                "version",
                                {},
                                "text",
                                "4.0"
                            ],
                            [
                                "fn",
                                {},
                                "text",
                                ""
                            ],
                            [
                                "tel",
                                {
                                    "type": "voice"
                                },
                                "uri",
                                "tel:8887802723"
                            ],
                            [
                                "email",
                                {},
                                "text",
                                "domainabuse@cscglobal.com"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "events": [
        {
            "eventAction": "registration",
            "eventDate": "2003-12-26T19:18:07Z"
        },
        {
            "eventAction": "expiration",
            "eventDate": "2024-02-02T11:59:59Z"
        },
        {
            "eventAction": "last changed",
            "eventDate": "2022-08-17T04:32:10Z"
        },
        {
            "eventAction": "last update of RDAP database",
            "eventDate": "2023-01-29T11:05:33Z"
        }
    ],
    "secureDNS": {
        "delegationSigned": false
    },
    "nameservers": [
        {
            "objectClassName": "nameserver",
            "ldhName": "NS-1033.AWSDNS-01.ORG"
        },
        {
            "objectClassName": "nameserver",
            "ldhName": "NS-358.AWSDNS-44.COM"
        },
        {
            "objectClassName": "nameserver",
            "ldhName": "NS-CLOUD-E1.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM"
        },
        {
            "objectClassName": "nameserver",
            "ldhName": "NS-CLOUD-E2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM"
        }
    ],
    "rdapConformance": [
        "rdap_level_0",
        "icann_rdap_technical_implementation_guide_0",
        "icann_rdap_response_profile_0"
    ],
    "notices": [
        {
            "title": "Terms of Use",
            "description": [
                "Service subject to Terms of Use."
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "https://www.verisign.com/domain-names/registration-data-access-protocol/terms-service/index.xhtml",
                    "type": "text/html"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Status Codes",
            "description": [
                "For more information on domain status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp"
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "https://icann.org/epp",
                    "type": "text/html"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "RDDS Inaccuracy Complaint Form",
            "description": [
                "URL of the ICANN RDDS Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://icann.org/wicf"
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "https://icann.org/wicf",
                    "type": "text/html"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

According to json2csharp.com the following custom type will do this:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
    public class Entity
    {
        public string objectClassName { get; set; }
        public List<string> roles { get; set; }
        public List<Remark> remarks { get; set; }
        public List<string> status { get; set; }
        public string handle { get; set; }
        public List<object> vcardArray { get; set; }
        public List<Entity> entities { get; set; }
        public List<PublicId> publicIds { get; set; }
        public List<Event> events { get; set; }
        public List<Link> links { get; set; }
    }

    public class Event
    {
        public string eventAction { get; set; }
        public DateTime eventDate { get; set; }
        public string eventActor { get; set; }
    }

    public class Link
    {
        public string rel { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }

    public class Nameserver
    {
        public string objectClassName { get; set; }
        public string handle { get; set; }
        public string ldhName { get; set; }
        public List<string> status { get; set; }
        public List<Event> events { get; set; }
        public List<Link> links { get; set; }
    }

    public class Notice
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public List<string> description { get; set; }
        public List<Link> links { get; set; }
    }

    public class PublicId
    {
        public string identifier { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Remark
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<string> description { get; set; }
        public List<Link> links { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<string> rdapConformance { get; set; }
        public string objectClassName { get; set; }
        public string handle { get; set; }
        public string ldhName { get; set; }
        public List<string> status { get; set; }
        public List<Event> events { get; set; }
        public SecureDNS secureDNS { get; set; }
        public List<Entity> entities { get; set; }
        public List<Nameserver> nameservers { get; set; }
        public List<Notice> notices { get; set; }
        public List<Link> links { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecureDNS
    {
        public bool delegationSigned { get; set; }
    }
```

And indeed, it does correctly deserialize that json into the type. There is just one very small and subtle problem: The line in the source code `public List<object> vcardArray { get; set; }` uses a list of "object", making access to the vcardArray very difficult. I'm currently converting each object to a string and using regexes to access them, however this doesn't seem right and feels finicky.

Is there any way I could modify the Entity class without using an 'object' for the vcardArray? Perhaps additional classes could be used? Every attempt I've made so far fails upon deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a VCard class and add JsonConstructor to Entity class

```
public class VCard
{
    public string CardType { get; set; }
    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    public string ValType { get; set; }
    public string Val { get; set; }
}
public class Entity
{
    //another properties

    public List<VCard> VCards { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Entity(JToken vcardArray)
    {
        VCards = vcardArray.OfType<JArray>()
                                 .Select(i => i.Select(x => new VCard
                                 {
                                     CardType = x[0].ToString(),
                                     ContactType = ((JObject)x[1]).Properties().Count() == 0 ? ""
                                                    : String.Join(",", ((JObject)x[1]).Properties()),
                                     ValType = x[2].ToString(),
                                     Val = x[3].ToString()
                                 })
                                  .ToList())
                                  .First();
    }
}
```